# get total number of queued jobs laravel -- RabbitMQ

Tags: php, queue, rabbitmq, laravel-5.1

new to `Laravel`, I'm using `RabbitMQ` with it, So, what I want is to get total number of `queued jobs` in some specific `queue`.

here are my connection details

```
RABBITMQ_HOST=Server
RABBITMQ_PORT=5672
RABBITMQ_VHOST=/
RABBITMQ_LOGIN=user
RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=password
RABBITMQ_QUEUE=testQueue
RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_NAME=testExchnge
```

any clue, or pointing to some tutorial to get total queued jobs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for any other, who is looking for the same thing, found a solution. Hope this will help.

I found the nice [Rrabbit MQ HTTP API](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/rabbitmq_v3_3_4/priv/www/api/index.html). There are a lot of endpoints there.

To get the messages from `Queues`, here is my code.

```
//laravel[lumen] based code.
public function loadQueueStats()
{
    $url = "http://" . env('RABBITMQ_HOST', '127.0.0.1') . ":" . env('RABBITMQ_PORT', 15672) . "/api/queues";
    $username = env('RABBITMQ_LOGIN', 'guest');
    $password = env('RABBITMQ_PASSWORD', 'guest');
    $response = $this->guzzle->get(
        $url,
        [
            'auth' => [
                $username,
                $password
            ],
        ]
    );
    return $response->json();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But What about the get a specific queue?

Like;
/api/queues/vhost/name/get

It is accepted  parameters following;

```
{"count":5,"ackmode":"ack_requeue_true","encoding":"auto","truncate":50000}
```

Comment: I don't know if you are asking a question or posting another one.